# Disassemble address line

Tags: place-names

Given the following address line

惠州市惠阳区秋长镇白石村朝鲲产业园三态速递

Which of it is the "street name", which the state and which the city?

I have to enter those fragments into a shipping address form. The available options for the state are as follows:

- 北京市
- 天津市
- 河北省
- 山西省
- 内蒙古自治区
- 辽宁省
- 吉林省
- 黑龙江省
- 上海市
- 江苏省
- 浙江省
- 安徽省
- 福建省
- 江西省
- 山东省
- 河南省
- 湖北省
- 湖南省
- 广东省
- 广西壮族自治区
- 海南省
- 重庆市
- 四川省
- 贵州省
- 云南省
- 西藏自治区
- 陕西省
- 甘肃省
- 青海省
- 宁夏回族自治区
- 新疆维吾尔自治区

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 惠州市惠阳区秋长镇白石村朝鲲产业园三态速递

There is no street name given.  Nor is there a province name given (although we can deduce the province is Guangdong).  What is given is:

> Huizhou
>   惠州市
>   <sub>Huìzhōu shì</sub>

The [市](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B8%82) here means "city".  We can deduce that [Huizhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huizhou) is in [Guangdong Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangdong) ([广东省](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%BF%E4%B8%9C%E7%9C%81), where [省](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%9C%81) means "province").

> Huiyang District
>   惠阳区
>   <sub>Huìyáng qū</sub>

The [区](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8C%BA) here means "district", and in this case it's the [Huiyang District](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huiyang_District); cities in China are broken up into areas called 区.

> Qiuchang Town
>   秋长镇
>   <sub>Qiūzhǎng zhèn</sub>

The [镇](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%95%87) here refers to a town and the surrounding areas; or maybe it could be better called "subdistrict" or "residential district" (the Wikipedia page for [Huiyang District](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huiyang_District) calls it 秋长街道).

> Baishi Village (White Stone Village)
>   白石村
>   <sub>Báishí cūn</sub>

The next level is a "village" [村](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9D%91), but it's not a village as a native English speaker would understand, but rather a "gated community" or an apartment complex.

The closest point I found on Baidu Maps is this village: [白石村](https://j.map.baidu.com/4b/ZVm).

> Chaokun Industrial Park
>   朝鲲产业园
>   <sub>Cháokūn chǎnyè yuán</sub>

The above means what it sounds like.

> Santai Courier
>   三态速递
>   <sub>Sāntài sùdì</sub>

This is the company name: [SFC](https://www.sfcservice.com/).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

惠州市city belongs to Guangdong province（广东省）
惠阳区district
秋长镇town
白石村village
朝鲲产业园industrial park
三态速递company name

Comment: When shopping on China’s website, they usually require ask address in the format of **“4 levels + street line”**. Level 1 (Province): 广东省¶ Level 2 (City): 惠州市¶ Level 3 (District): 惠阳区¶ Level 4 (Town): 秋长镇¶ Street Line: 白石村朝鲲产业园三态速递¶ Meanwhile, thank @ThreveNine 379叁百七十九 for providing information.